# Create a backup on a remote share using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a backup script that is supposed to target a specific local folder and backup the folder to a remote shared folder on another server.

When I run my script, Powershell prompts me with the following error:

*One of the file paths specified for backup is that of a remote shared folder. Backup of a remote shared folder is not allowed.*

The following code is the cause for the underlying issue:

```
$current_day = ("\\backupsrv01\Homes\" + $day)
```

The variable **$day** is just the current day.

```
$date = Get-Date
$day = $date.DayOfWeek
```

How can I successfully target a remote share using Powershell?

Comment: If I'm reading the error message correctly, it's saying that you're trying to backup a remote shared folder, not backup **to** a remote shared folder.

Comment: I feel that your question should be asked at http://stackoverflow.com/ rather than here. However follow their [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements: please [edit] your quetion and  show backup code snippet with source(s) and target. I agree with @GregL.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to get at what you're trying to do here (What backup software? What else is in your script?) But i'll give it a shot...

You could try invoking the Powershell onto the remote server

An example of how this can work is

```
function MyBackup {
    # Whatever you backup is doing 
}

$Credz = Get-Credential
$MySession = New-PSSession $TargetServer -Credential $Credz
Invoke-Command -Session $MySession -ScriptBlock ${function:MyBackup}
```

That way the Powershell you're running is running on the targethost as opposed to your machine running it.

If you need to pass parameters into a function you're Invoking that can be done like so

```
$Item = "Cap"
$Colour = "Red"

function RemoteParameters {
    param($Item, $Colour)
    Write-Host "The $Item is $Colour"
}

Invoke-Command -Session $MySession -ScriptBlock ${function:RemoteParameters} -ArguementList $Item,$Colour
```